# linear gradient with box-shadow on round button

Tags: css, linear-gradients, radial-gradients

I'm trying to create a button similar to these http://houseofbuttons.tumblr.com/post/16760351131/starred-checked-action-buttons-by-brendon

and was hoping to do it with just css.

I put together a quick jsfiddle page http://jsfiddle.net/ne69E (but I haven't been able to get it to work, though I do see the round element with the same code without jsfiddle).

Before I spend too much time doing this, I wanted to make sure that it is possible to create a linear gradient over a radial gradient. I tried using the background-image: linear gradient, but that only applies to the div, not the borders.

What do you think? is it possible? Or should I just use images?

Answer (score 1):

Your jsfiddle has a couple errors (you wrote webit instead of webkit and you're using numbers like 4 and 7 with no units), check this [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/9mV8k/2/), and it seems you're not so far off from an effect like the ones on the buttons you want.

Comment: thanks for sorting those things out for me. I know I'm not far away, but I've only got radial gradients, which won't create the same effect as having a linear gradient over a radial.